# Using Selenium Event Listener & TestNG Listeners in conjunction to log test specific data

Tags: selenium, testng, event-listener

My objective is to have test specific logging using Selenium & TestNG Listeners.

Problem Statement: TestNG runs 3 threads / selenium tests in parallel and each selenium test does some operations on web pages.

Hypothetical Test1:
Open Application URL
Login as customer
Logout

Hypothetical Test2:
Open Application URL
Browse different products on a page.
Login as customer
Logout

Hypothetical Test3:
Open Application URL
Browse different products on a page.
Select a product for purchase
Login as customer
Make Payment on the credit card
Logout

Now, whatever clicks / navigation / findby happen on whatever page, that will be logged by Selenium Event Listener (to a log file or a database or whatever other place)

The Selenium Web Event Listener logging would be random according to which thread has executed what command. And there is no mapping of the test name and selenium event listener generated log.

Assume TM1 is the testNG test name- I'd like to have something like

1. TM1 - Navigated to the [URL]
2. TM1 - Clicked on Login link
3. TM1 - Clicked on Logout Link

Is there a way I can achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be create custom logging and override default behaviour of TestNG listener methods.
Refer to this link http://www.seleniumeasy.com/testng-tutorials/logging-with-testng-using-listeners. This will give you some idea on how to implement custom logging. You can combine Selenium with TestNG logs together.

Comment: Thanks mate. I'll try that and see if that solves the problem.